# Phoenix: Broadcasting from IEx console

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have built a small chat app like the one here:
https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example/blob/master/web/channels/room_channel.ex

And cannot figure out how to broadcast to all users in a topic a message. In the above application (which isn't updated to v0.13 like I'm using), how would I do that? Below is what I've tried with no luck:

```
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast Chat.PubSub, "new:msg", "hello from the console"
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast Chat.Endpoint, "new:msg", "hello from the console"
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast Chat.RoomChannel, "new:msg", "hello from the console"
```

None of them work... A few of them throw exceptions :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are on 0.13, you need to broadcast off the endpoint, and you need to provide the topic, event, and payload (as a map). Try this:

```
Chat.Endpoint.broadcast("rooms:lobby", "new:msg", %{message: "hello from the console"})
```

This snippet makes some assumptions about your channel and client code, so if it doesn't work, please provide your router, channel, and js code so I can help further.